# How to shuffle a list by omitting certain characters in Python

Tags: python, list

I am a middle school student studying Python. Is there a way to omit certain characters from the list and mix them?

**Input list**

```
['Hello', 'Middle school student', 'I am']
```

**Expected output**

```
['Middle school student', 'Hello', 'I am']
```

If you specify is, everything except for is mixed.

Comment: Your question doesn't match your example.  What you have demonstrated is simple shuffling, and that's easy in Python.  If you need more, you'll need to provide a more thorough example.

Comment: You can use `random.shuffle()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple shuffle that is effective and efficient.  Basically, you randomly swap each element with another element.

```
import random
def shuffle(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        j = random.randrange(len(lst))
        lst[i],lst[j] = lst[j],lst[i]
```